# Show specific block of text on 1 of 2 Zendesk ticket forms

Tags: javascript, html, zendesk

I'm attempting to display a specific chunk of text on 1 of 2 ticket forms within Zendesk.

i.e

Ticket form 1 - no special text visible
Ticket form 2 - special text only visible when this form as been selected

I've got the text I have to dislpay set up in a div on the new_requests_page. When I text it at the moment the text is visible on both ticket forms.

I'm hoping someone can help me with the javascript code I would need in order for my text to display on the specific ticket form.

ticket_form_id='360001721394'

Below is my current code for the page. I do have some javascript on there which Hides/shows the text when a button is clicked. However on top of that, I really want to achieve this special text to only be visible on the specific form when a customer selects that form.

---

```
<div class="container-divider"></div>
<div class="container">
  <nav class="sub-nav">
    {{breadcrumbs}}
    {{search submit=false}}
  </nav>

  <h1>
    {{t 'submit_a_request'}}
    {{#if follow_up}}
      <span class="follow-up-hint">
        {{follow_up}}
      </span>
    {{/if}}
  </h1>

  <div class="form-disclaimer">
  <div class="btn-hide">
   <button id="hide">Hide/Show</button>

    </div>

<div class="disclaimer-title">
  <p>External Credit Reporting Bodies
  </div>
<div class="disclaimer-subtitle">
<p>Verify your identity with a credit reporting body</p>
  </div>

<p>Latitude is required by the Anti-Money Laundering &amp; Counter-Terrorism Financing Act 2006 to verify my identity before providing me with a product or service.<br>

By acknowledging this statement, I agree I have read this information and allow Latitude to provide personal information about me to credit reporting bodies to enable verification of my identity.<br><br>

Personal information that Latitude may provide to the credit reporting body includes:<br></p>

  <ul>
  <li>&bull; My full name</li>
    <li>&bull; My address</li>
    <li>&bull; My date of birth</li>
  </ul>


<p> I understand that in addition to the circumstances described in the privacy consent, my personal information will be used by the credit reporting body and by Latitude to assess whether the information provided by Latitude matches the information held about me by the credit reporting body for the purpose of verifying my identity. I also understand that use of my personal information in this way does not constitute a credit check or impact my credit standing in any way.<br><br>

The credit reporting body may inform Latitude as to whether the personal information provided is a full or partial match with information held by it. Latitude cannot rectify any discrepancies but will advise me by letter or email and provide contact details of the credit reporting body where I can confirm my details.<br><br>

Verification with a credit reporting body is the fastest way to establish your identity however, Latitude offers alternatives, for anyone not wishing to use their personal information held at a credit reporting body. We will attempt to verify you using alternative electronic verification means.<br><br> </p>
<div class="disclaimer-title">  
<p>Australian Government Document Verification Service</p>
  </div>
<div class="disclaimer-subtitle">
<p>Checking your identity with the Australian Government's Document Verification Service (DVS).</p>
  </div>
<p>The DVS is a national online system that allows organisations to compare an individual's identifying information with a government record.<br><br>

More information about the DVS is available on their website.<br><br>

By submitting your details on this page, you agree that:<br>
  <span>
    <ul>
      <li>&bull; You're authorised to provide the details; and</li>
            <li>&bull; You understand the details will be checked against records held by the Issuer or Official Record Holder.</li>
        </ul>
        </span>
  </p>
</div>


  <div class="form">
    {{request_form}}
  </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").toggle();
  $("ul").toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

---

I am new to javascript and teaching myself. Hoping there might be someone kind enough here to write the piece of javascript I need to get this working?

I know what i want the javascript to say, i just dont know how to execute it.

if ticket form = 360001721394 than display this div "form-disclaimer"

Thanks in advance and regards,

Amie

Comment: Hi provide some id to the particular p tag and in jquery call it through id

Answer (score 0):

You can get the url of the current page and check for your ticket form id via `window.location.href.indexOf`, like below example to then show the div you mentioned.  See if this helpos

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('ticket_form_id=360001721394') > -1) {
  $('.form-disclaimer').show();
}
```